# Should GroupPrincipal supply ALL AD fileds?

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.2

VisualStudio 2019, C#, .NetCore 2.2

Something odd is happening.  I have the following code.  It *works* but if I put a breakpoint on the `var thing = member;` line I can see that `member` has a lot of object.member values.  Things like: EmailAddress and other AD fields.  However, in the editor if I try to use `member.EmailAddress` I get the message that`EmailAddress` can not be resolved.

I am pretty sure that the user/pass pair for the `PrincipalContext` is a "privileged" account that should have access to all AD fields, if that matters.

```
    using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
        "ad.myCompany.com",  userName:"ad-svc-account", "...")) {
        var grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.DistinguishedName,
            "CN=My Group Staff,OU=Groups - DLs,OU=My,OU=Org,DC=ad,DC=myCompany,DC=com");

        if (grp == null) {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Group list is empty");
        }

        foreach (var member in grp.Members) {
            var thing = member;
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When you go through the members of the group by using `var member`, you are iterating over the members of type `Principal`<sup>[1]</sup>. `Principal` type itself doesnt have the details that you would normally see on a `GroupPrincipal`<sup>[2]</sup> or perhaps a `UserPrincipal`<sup>[3]</sup>.

Since the member of the groups could either be UserPrincipal or GroupPrincipal or other types, you will need to first figure out the type of the Principal you are working with, **cast** it to the correct type and then look up all the properties.

```
foreach(var member in grp.Members) 
{
  if (member is UserPrincipal)
  {
      var memberP = member as UserPrincipal;
      memberP.<will have all the properties of UserPrincipal>;
  }
  else if (member is GroupPrincipal)
  {
      var memberG = member as GroupPrincipal;
      memberG.<will have all properties of GroupPrincipal>;
  }
  else
  {
    //handle other types (such as ComputerPrincipal) or all others.
  }
}
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup>[Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal?view=netframework-4.8)

> Initializes a new instance of the Principal class. This constructor is called by derived-class constructors to initialize the base class and is not intended to be called directly from your code

<sup>[2]</sup>[GroupPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal?view=netframework-4.8)

> Encapsulates group accounts. Group accounts can be arbitrary collections of principal objects or accounts created for administrative purposes

<sup>[3]</sup>[UserPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal?view=netframework-4.8)

> Encapsulates principals that are user accounts